# C# design pattern when you find yourself in need of events to be executed in specific order

Tags: c#, events, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm making a game in C# where two different classes are notified via events when the player moves.

One of those classes is the `RenderGrid`, as soon as the player moves the RenderGrid will instantiate only the new game tiles now visible on screen. It also contains two vectors describing the bottomLeft and topRight corners of the grid that is currently being rendered

The other is the `WorldManager` class, which as soon as the player moves, will check if there's the need to load and create new chunks of the game world. To do so, it needs to check the corners of the `RenderGrid` to ensure they're still inside the boundaries of already loaded chunks.

And here is the problem, since `WorldManager` *depends* on the event being handled first on `RenderGrid` and then on `WorldManager` thus breaking the event pattern

In pseudo-code, here's RenderGrid:

```
public class RenderGrid 
{

    public Vector2 bottomLeft;
    public Vector2 topRight;

    public RenderGrid() 
    {
        Player.onPlayerMoved += playerMoved;
    }

    ~RenderGrid() 
    {
        Player.onPlayerMoved -= playerMoved;
    }

    private void playerMoved(Vector2 delta, Vector2 position) 
    {
        // updates the bottomLeft and topRight corners
    }
}
```

And WorldGrid:

```
public class WorldGrid 
{
    public WorldGrid() 
    {
        Player.onPlayerMoved += playerMoved;
    }

    ~WorldGrid() 
    {
        Player.onPlayerMoved -= playerMoved;
    }

    private void playerMoved(Vector2 delta, Vector2 position) 
    {
        // it needs the corners of the renderGrid, but since those are also updated when player moves, we can't be sure
        // wheter they've been updated here or not
    }
}
```

Using a separate event to notify that the `RenderGrid` corners have been updated and listening to it seems like sure spaghetti and I'm not sure how to proceed from here

Comment: Maybe a priority queue of sorts? The separate event seems like the right way to go

Comment: You have no choice, really. Multi-cast delegate calling order is NOT guaranteed.

Comment: Aren't priority queues better suited when more than just two delegate calls needs to be executed?

Comment: I am under the impression that destructors are frowned on in C#, and you should be using the `Dispose()` method instead, and make sure that your class implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: I'll make sure to look into it, thanks everyone for your useful inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Chain the events

Seems like the `RenderGrid` should handle the event that indicates the player moved. `RenderGrid` can then publish events of its own. The `WorldGrid` would subscribe to these events, thus it would only fire if the Rendergrid has finished its processing.

The typical pattern is to set up custom event args, delegate, and handlers, as shown in the following:

Custom event args, handler delegate:

```
public class PlayerMovedEventArgs
{
    public Vector2 Delta { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
}

public delegate void PlayerMovedHandler(object sender, PlayerMovedEventArgs e);
```

Then the Rendergrid:

```
public class RenderGrid 
{
    public Vector2 bottomLeft;
    public Vector2 topRight;
    public Player _player;

    public event PlayerMovedHandler Changed;

    public RenderGrid(Player player) 
    {
        _player = player;
        _player.OnPlayerMoved += PlayerMovedInGrid;
    }

    private void UpdateCorners(Vector2 delta, Vector2 position)
    {
        //ToDo: Update corners
    }
    private void PlayerMovedInGrid(object sender, PlayerMovedEventArgs e) 
    {
        UpdateCorners(e.Delta, e.Position);
        OnChanged(e);
    }

    protected void OnChanged(PlayerMovedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Changed != null) Changed(this, e);
    }
}
```

And finally the WorldGrid. The important change here is that WorldGrid subscribes to RenderGrid's events (not Player's).

```
public class WorldGrid 
{
    private readonly Player _player;
    private readonly RenderGrid _renderGrid;

    public WorldGrid(Player player, RenderGrid renderGrid) 
    {
        _player = player;
        _renderGrid = renderGrid;
        _renderGrid.Changed += this.PlayerMovedInWorld;
    }

    private void PlayerMovedInWorld(object sender, PlayerMovedEventArgs e) 
    {
        // it needs the corners of the renderGrid, but since those are also updated when player moves, we can't be sure
        // wheter they've been updated here or not
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from legendary disputes here on SO about whether event order being guaranteed or not:

ask yourself, who has the greatest responsibility for responding to the event, then this one should respond first. On that basis, what's wrong with registering another event (with a different name) between WorldGrid and RenderGrid?

If RenderGrid is owned by WorldGrid or vice versa you could even just define and call RenderGrid.NotifyContentLoaded or WorldGrid.NotifyBordersChanged.